# i need to display Number of RX packets and the number of TX packets for the loopback interface

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, loopback

im new to linux and i need to display Number of RX packets and the number of TX packets for the loopback interface. i have tried using ipcongif but for reason i get an error, im using ubuntu for windows. any help. thank you
`ipconfig`

Comment: i have tried ```ifconfig lo```` and it works in online ubuntu server, is there anything i can do to just show the rx and tx packets.

Comment: Please add to your answer the program you are running and the answer you get. What is Ubuntu for Windows? WSL?

Comment: ```ifconfig lo```, lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 817  bytes 71380 (71.3 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 817  bytes 71380 (71.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0.

Comment: im not getting an error message when i perform this command on ubuntu online but when i try this command on my windows ubuntu then i get the error, command cannot be found

Comment: Ubuntu on Windows is just a way to run some commands on top of Windows. It is not Ubuntu.

Comment: ok, i'll download putty but do you know what i can do about the rx.tx packet?

Comment: You should start by saying you are not really using a Linux system

Comment: You might be missing the point, you are running Windows with some ported utilities, not Ubuntu. That's why it is unlikely that somebody here will answer.

Comment: like i said before, i am using both ubuntu for windows as well as a ubuntu server online to test the commands, so i am using a linux system. the only reason i have ubuntu for windows is to test commands

Answer (score 1):

As has been said in the comments, WSL is not a true Linux environment; I don't even get packet counts in WSL2 (`ifconfig` outputs all zeroes).

At any rate, `ifconfig` has been superseded by `ip` so that's probably why it's not installed by default. You probably want `ip -s link show dev lo`.

[Linux Network Statistics Tools / Commands - nixCraft](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/network-statistics-tools-rhel-centos-debian-linux/)